# failed to connect to all addresses exception when trying to connect GRPC server from a winforms app

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, grpc-c#

Hello grpc newbie here,

I've a winforms application that I want to connect to a grpc server.

I have no problem running the grpc server on localhost and make a connection to it with the winforms app.

I've deployed my grpc server to a temporary url : http://mujf94-001-site1.gtempurl.com/

but when I try to connect it I get the following error:

```
Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="failed to connect to all addresses", 
DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: 
{"created":"@1630271164.373000000","description":"Failed to pick 
subchannel","file":"..\..\..\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc",
"file_line":3009,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1630271164.373000000","description":
"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"..\..\..\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\
lb_policy\pick_first\pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}")
```

This is how I try connecting to the grpc server:

```
        var ip = "mujf94-001-site1.gtempurl.com".ToIPAddress();

        var channel = new Channel(ip.ToString(),80, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);

        //var channel = new Channel("http://mujf94-001-site1.gtempurl.com", 80, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);

        Client = channel.CreateGrpcService<T>();
```

and my grpc server options are like this:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.Listen("mujf94-001-site1.gtempurl.com".ToIPAddress(), 80, o => o.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2);
                });
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

I'm very new to this so any help is very appreciated

Comment: Did you try turning on the logs to see what the connection errors are? https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md